# node js event loop . why setImmediate is called last(almost last)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry if it is a dumb question but I'm trying to crack node js event loop and reading about phases and how they work so I don't understand at all why setImmediate is called last

As we know Event loop cycle is divided into phases:

1. Timers
2. Pending callbacks(I/O)
3. Idle, prepare
4. Poll
5. Check
6. Close callbacks

I came up with some example

```
console.log(1);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(7);
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(9));
});
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(7.5);
    Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(10));
});
setInterval(() => console.log(8),1000);

setImmediate(() => {
  console.log(1.5);
});

Promise.resolve(2).then(console.log);
queueMicrotask(() => console.log(2.5));

process.nextTick(() => console.log(3));
process.nextTick(() => console.log(3.5));

console.log(4);
```

And node js tells me that output

```
1  
4  
3  
3.5
2  
2.5
7  
9  
1.5
8
8
...interval call
```

Okay, as per tutorials I understand that my sync code is run in Poll phase and then I expect nextTicks callbacks to be shown after current operation (sync code). and as far as I know it should be Check phase next and we've already registered setImmediate code in our sync code so I expected it to be run but it didn't! Why that?

And could you please tell me in which phase Microtasks queue is run?Before Timers phase? I can't see anywhere this information specified... It's clearer how they are called and run in browser

Comment: As I understood , setImmediate is called in the next iteration of the loop